# Possible to modify the Layout View value on the fly in a custom View Engine?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Currently I have a custom view engine that will detect a setting in the application configuration file and append a string to the end of view files accordingly. To use states as an example, if it detected Vermont it would append `"_VT"` to the end of View file names. It works fine, and if there is no `"_VT"` found it defaults to the file without any special ending.

Inside of my Razor Views I can use the `Layout = ""` option to specify a Layout for the View. My question is, is there a way I can do a similar thing to the Layout as I have done in the View Engine? Basically, if Vermont is detected in config, add `"_VT"` to the Layout View file name.

Current View Engine:

```
public class PlanSpecificRazorViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    public PlanSpecificRazorViewEngine()
    {
        ViewLocationFormats = new[] { "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml", "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml" };
        PartialViewLocationFormats = new[] { "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml", "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml" };
        AreaViewLocationFormats = new[] { "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml", "~/Areas/{1}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml" };
        AreaPartialViewLocationFormats = new [] {"~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml", "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml" };
    }

    public override ViewEngineResult FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewName, string masterName, bool useCache)
    {
        string Plan = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Plan"];
        return base.FindView(controllerContext, viewName + "_" + Plan, masterName, useCache);
    }

    public override ViewEngineResult FindPartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string partialViewName, bool useCache)
    {
        string Plan = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Plan"];
        return base.FindPartialView(controllerContext, partialViewName + "_" + Plan, useCache);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the default `MasterLocationFormats` in the constructor:

```
public PlanSpecificRazorViewEngine()
{
    ...

    string Plan = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Plan"];
    MasterLocationFormats = new string[] 
    { 
        "~/Views/Shared/{0}_" + Plan + ".cshtml",
        "~/Views/Shared/{0}_" + Plan + ".vbhtml"
    };
}
```

Comment: Would it default if there was no custom layout found, meaning if there is _SideBarLayout and _SideBarLayout_VT but no _SidebarLayout_VA and Virginia is found, it defaults to _SidebarLayout? That is how it works with the View names, which I think is default behavior for the RazorViewEngine.